# How to instantly or immediately update state using in react using useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

While utilizing the useState hook, I encountered difficulties in achieving immediate state updates. In order to use the useState hook effectively, I needed to find ways that allowed me to make prompt state updates.

Answer (score 0):

The useState hook in React is synchronous, but the re-rendering process can make the state update appear asynchronous.

***asynchronous** - (non-blocking architecture)

***synchronous** - (blocking architecture)

In React, utilizing the useState hook to update state may give the impression that setting the state is asynchronous. While useState is inherently synchronous, the subsequent chain of events triggered by changing the state unfolds asynchronously. This can create the perception that state updates are not instantaneous and require the component to re-render before taking effect.

For immediate state updates, consider utilizing either objects or arrays, as they are both suitable options rather than using strings or numbers. A useState change in object values instantaneously updates the state.

For example:

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({name: “ ”’,  age: 18});
setInputs(prevState => ({...prevState, age: newAge, name: ‘My newName’});

<input name='name' value={inputs?.name}/>
<input name='age' value={inputs?.age}/>
```

Making changes using string or number within useState hook does not instantaneously update the state.

```
const [nameInput, setNameInput] = useState(“ “);
const [ageInput, setAgeInput] = useState(0);
setNameInput(‘My newName’); \\ will not instantaneously make a state update
setAgeInput(44); \\ will not instantaneously make a state update
```